# How to make Chart Line in Layout Android

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

How to make Chart like picture in a view Android. I used to libs MPAndroidChart
but it's not suitable. Any libs else? Help me to make it

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtEcZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not with MPAndroidChart ?

You can export chart as a picture and save to your gallery with:

```
myChart.saveToGallery(String title)
```

or get the Bitmap object with:

```
myChart.getChartBitmap()
```

See documentation [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Miscellaneous) for more informations.